# Como interpretar la politica de acceso en XACML

Tags: xml

tengo problemas con XACML y no entiendo este código de XACML a ver si alguien me puede ayudar:

```html
<Policy xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17"  PolicyId="1" 
  RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:rule-combining-algorithm:first-applicable" 
  Version="1.0">
    <Description>My First Policy </Description>
    <Target></Target>
    <Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="Rule Permit #1">
      <Target>
        <AnyOf>
          <AllOf>
            <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-regexp-match">
              <AttributeValue 
DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">http://www.defense.gov/area51
              </AttributeValue>
              <AttributeDesignator 
  AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" 
  Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" 
  DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true">
       </AttributeDesignator>
            </Match>
            <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
              <AttributeValue 
                DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">read
       </AttributeValue>
              <AttributeDesignator 
  AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" 
  Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action" 
  DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true">
       </AttributeDesignator>
            </Match>
          </AllOf>
        </AnyOf>
      </Target>
      <Condition>
        <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-at-least-one-member-of">
          <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-bag">
            <AttributeValue  
              DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">fbi 
           </AttributeValue>
    <AttributeValue 
       DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">cia
            </AttributeValue>
          </Apply>
          <AttributeDesignator 
            AttributeId="group" 
     Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:group" 
     DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true">
          </AttributeDesignator>
        </Apply>
      </Condition>
   </Rule>
   <Rule Effect="Deny" RuleId="Rule Deny #1"></Rule>
</Policy>
```

Comment: Pero cual es el problema, o que es lo que no entiendes, sin esa información no te podemos ayudar mucho

Comment: Hola @javier, bienvenido a SOes, te sugiero ampliar tu pregunta,podrías por ejemplo, aclarar que es lo que no entiendes? el comportamiento? etc..

Comment: Lo que no entiendo es el comportamiento de de esta política de XACML y como podría modificarla  para que se pueda actualizar (update) el recurso http://www.defense.gov/area51 sólo si el usuario pertenece al mismo tiempo a los grupos “fbi” y “cia”. En el caso que no pertenezca a ambos grupos o pertenezca a ellos pero también a alguno más, no podrá realizar la actualización.

Comment: A lo mejor no me explicado lo suficientemente bien.